# flask server won't run if I named my application factory function other than "create_app"

Tags: python, flask

My server will run if I name application factory function as `create_app` like this:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
       return 'Hello, World!'

    return app
```

but naming it other than `create_app`, will throw an error `Failed to find Flask application or factory`

```
def foo_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    return app
```

changing the case will also throw the same error, like this:

```
def Create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    return app
```

Is this behavior is normal? or is there something wrong in my setup?

this is my project layout:

```
...\projects\mainfoo
|--packagefoo
|    |--__init__.py
|--venvfiles
```

in the cmd,

```
...\projects\mainfoo>set FLASK_APP=packagefoo
...\projects\mainfoo>set FLASK_ENV=development
...\projects\mainfoo>flask run
```

I just follow this tutorial [Project Layout](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/layout/) & [Application setup](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/factory/)

Comment: Where are you calling your create_app function from?

Comment: I set the FLASK_APP at the outside of the folder/package where the `__init__.py` is located, is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/cli/#application-discovery)

> `$ export FLASK_APP=hello`
>
> `$ flask run`
>
> While **FLASK_APP** supports a variety of options for specifying your
> application, most use cases should be simple. Here are the typical
> values:
>
> (nothing)
>
> The name “app” or “wsgi” is imported (as a “.py” file, or
> package), automatically detecting an app (app or application) or
> factory (create_app or make_app).
>
> **FLASK_APP=hello**
>
> The given name is imported, automatically detecting an
> **app (app or application)** or factory **(create_app or make_app)**.

You cannot customize this behavior, as its a specification in flask to follow.

Comment: Ah okay it just either `create_app` or `make_app`, I'm sorry I didn't know this part, I though there is something wrong in my setup